# Getting an error during the installation process

Tags: windows-7, installation

I'm on a [VAIO laptop, VPCS116FG model](http://www.sony-asia.com/product/vpcs116fg). I got an error while installing [FreeFileOpener](http://www.freefileopener.com/download.html):

[image]

Is it possible to find out what causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes clearing cache & cookies would resolve the issue.

After that just restart your PC and try to install **FreeFileOpener**.